# Automatically Connect to OpenVPN Server on Boot

Tags: windows, boot, openvpn, login

I have been looking online for an answer to starting an OpenVPN client on boot. Every tutorial I have looked at only starts it when a user logs in. How do I set up Windows to automatically connect to the OpenVPN Server on boot?

Answer (score 1):

From [Run OpenVPN as a service](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/):

1. Ensure 'Install Service' mode box is checked when installing OpenVPN Client
2. Open `%WinDir%\system32\services.msc` and set OpenVPN to Automatic Start mode.

When OpenVPN runs as a service, it will start a separate OpenVPN process for each configuration file (*.ovpn) it finds in `%ProgramFiles%\OpenVPN\config\`.

You can edit the registry to confirm/change the directory the service wrapper checks, what extension it checks for, which version of the openvpn client is run, and where the logs are kept. See the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Correction in Andy answer,

To Run OpenVPN as a service:

1. Ensure 'Install Service' mode box is checked when installing OpenVPN Client
   Open %WinDir%\system32\services.msc and set OpenVPNService to Automatic Start mode.
2. When OpenVPN runs as a service, it will start a separate OpenVPN process for each configuration file(*.ovpn) it finds in "%ProgramFiles%\OpenVPN\config-auto" Folder

For more information refer to the OpenVPN website

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/